# Correlate data from two dataframes into one, retaining original ones' info

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I must transform information from two data frames into a matrix which is very specifically designed for my further analysis. I will start by introducing a toy example of the type of data I am working with.

```
Game1 <- structure(list(Score1 = c(5, 9), Score2 = c(4.8, 12.8), Score3 = c(7.22, 
2.3), Class = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Dwarf", "Paladin"), class = "factor"), 
    Race = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Dwarf,", "Elf"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("Stan", 
"Kyle"), class = "data.frame")

Game2 <- structure(list(Score1 = c(3, 8.1), Score2 = c(6.3, 6.6), Score3 = c(1.2, 
10.3), Class = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Rouge", "Wizard"), class = "factor"), 
    Race = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Gnome", "Human,"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("Cartman", 
"Kenny"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to perform a correlation of the scores for the different players, the ideal would be an average pearsons correlation. I would like to retain certain residual features from the original two data frames, which is shown below.

The output I wish from this is:

```
             Correlation Game1_Class Game1_Race Game2_Class Game2_Race

Stan:Cartman   -0.815    Paladin     Dwarf      Wizard      Human
Kyle:Cartman    0.942    Fighter     Elf        Wizard      Human
Stan:Kenny      0.947    Wizard      Human      Ranger      Gnome
Kyle:Kenny     -0.998    Rouge       Gnome      Ranger      Gnome
```

I've used a generic coefficient correlation to work out the correlations, I would prefer to use pearsons or spearman.

The number of rows in each data frame (in my real data) are vastly different.

Comment: Try to have a summarized and more general title. Your title is merely about giving a tip not describing it completely. It should be clear, short and about the general problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a customized function that creates such table

```
name_combn <- expand.grid(rownames(Game1), rownames(Game2),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cor_table <- function(names,df1, df2){
   n1 <- as.character(names[1])
   n2 <- as.character(names[2])
   # 1:3 are the col. positions with numeric scores:
   r <- cor(as.numeric(df1[n1, 1:3]),as.numeric(df2[n2, 1:3])) 
  data.frame(names = paste(n1,":",n2, sep = ""),cor =r, 
             df1[n1, -c(1:3)],
             df2[n2, -c(1:3)], row.names = "")
}


df <- do.call(rbind,apply(name_combn, 1, cor_table, df1 = Game1, df2 = Game2))

 #  names         cor         Class   Race Class.1 Race.1
 #  Stan:Cartman -0.8154535   Paladin Dwarf  Wizard Human
 #  Kyle:Cartman  0.9472246   Dwarf   Elf    Wizard Human
 #  Stan:Kenny    0.9426604   Paladin Dwarf  Rouge  Gnome
 #  Kyle:Kenny   -0.9987835   Dwarf   Elf    Rouge  Gnome
```